# Problem with PlatformExceptions / activitys

Tags: android, flutter

im having an issue with the error i posted, its my first time dealing with this kind of issue and i cant seem to fix it or even understand how to fix it, i would greatly appreciate some help or guidance in order to understand how to resolve this error.

I have also attached my android manifest if needed!

`PlatformException(error, Unable to find explicit activity class {com.arcdevelopment.thepack/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?, null, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.arcdevelopment.thepack/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?`

````
    package="com.arcdevelopment.thepack">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>

        <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>

         <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

   <application
        android:label="The Pack"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
       <!-- Set up the Sign in with Apple activity, such that it's callable from the browser-redirect -->
       <activity
               android:name="com.aboutyou.dart_packages.sign_in_with_apple.SignInWithAppleCallback"
               android:exported="true"
       >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

               <data android:scheme="signinwithapple" />
               <data android:path="callback" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity android:name=".myActivity"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"

              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>```
````

Comment: Unable to find explicit activity class ```{com.arcdevelopment.thepack/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity}```; have you declared this activity in your ```AndroidManifest.xml```, or does your intent not match its declared ```<intent-filter>```?

Comment: So from what i read/ tried with thsi informatios is making a class right? or am i lost

Comment: When you create a new ```Activity```, you have to also mention it in your ```AndroidManifest.xml```. So you will have to add at least one line like ```<activity android:name=".UCropActivity" />``` within ```<application>``` tag in your ```AndroidManifest.xml```.

Comment: Solved it, thank you!